# Basic Probability question depending on $P(A)$ and $P(B)$

Tags: probability

I have the following question: Suppose the probability of event $A$ and event $B$ are $P(A)$ and $P(B)$, respectively. 
Let even $C$ be $A$ occurrs and $B$ does not occur. Would then the probability of $C$ be 
$$
P(C)=P(A)+P(B^c)-P(A\cap B^c)
$$
Is there also a way of expressing $P(C)$ only in terms of $P(A)$, $P(B)$ and $P(A\cap B)$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: $P(B^c) = 1 - P(B)$

Comment: Use `\cap` not `\bigcap` for a binary intersection.

Comment: The event $C=A\cap B^c$.

Answer (score 4):

If $C$ is the event that $A$ occurs and $B$ does not occur, then $C=A\cap B^c$, so $\mathbb{P}(C)=\mathbb{P}(A\cap B^c)$.

And since $B\cup B^c=\Omega$ and $B$ and $B^c$ are disjoint, it follows that $\mathbb{P}(A)=\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)+\mathbb{P}(A\cap B^c)$. Therefore $$\mathbb{P}(C)=\mathbb{P}(A\cap B^c)=\mathbb{P}(A)-\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)$$

Comment: Thank you! Is there a similar way to express exactly one of A or B occuring?

Comment: Yes, there is something called the symmetric difference: $A\Delta B=(A\cap B^c)\cup (A^c\cap B)$.

Comment: .... and $\def\P{\mathop{\sf P}} \P(A\Delta B) = \P(A)+\P(B)-2\P(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 0):

Simply, $$P(C)=P(A\cap B^c)=P(A)-(A\cap B)$$